# Java: BufferedStreams and event handlers

Tags: swing, events, event-handling, buffer

I'm working on a "console" using a JTextArea, and everything works great, except that I the output is not working like I want it to.

I am using a modified version of a class I found here on Stackoverflow.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class textareaStream extends OutputStream {

//*************************
//* Parameters
//*************************
private JTextArea textArea; // target text area
private byte[] aByte;     // array for write(int val);

//*************************
//* Constructor
//*************************
public textareaStream(JTextArea ta) {
    textArea=ta;
    aByte=new byte[1];
}


//*************************
//* Writing methods
//*************************
public void write(int val) {
    aByte[0]=(byte)val;
    write(aByte,0,1);
}

public void write(byte[] ba) {
    write(ba,0,ba.length);
}

public synchronized void write(byte[] ba,int str,int len) {
    try {
        for(int xa=0; xa<10; xa++) {
            try {
                textArea.append(new String(ba,str,len));
                break;
            } catch(Throwable thr) {
                if (xa==9) {
                    thr.printStackTrace();
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Throwable thr) {
        CharArrayWriter caw=new CharArrayWriter();
        thr.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(caw,true));
        textArea.append(System.getProperty("line.separator","\n"));
        textArea.append(caw.toString());
    }
}
}
```

This is working great, except when the "write" method is called from an event handler.

In an event handler, the text is not written to the textarea until the event is finished running. What I want is for the text to be written to the console as the command runs (this is especially needed for time consuming commands). In other words, when the user hits the enter key (for example), a long process runs while printing data to the JTextArea, but the text does not show up until *after* the whole process has been run.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are using your class from within some event handler and calling `write` method there. If that's the case, you can use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method. See this for example:

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml

Basically, you'd create a helper method along these lines:

```
private void writeOnEDT(final byte[] ba, final int str, final int len) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      instance.write(ba, str, len); 
    }
  });
}
```

where `instance` is an instance of your `textareaStream` class. If you decide to put this in the same class, just remove `instance.` and use `writeOnEDT` instead of `write`, it should work properly.

Note that whatever long-running job you have must **not** execute on EDT - otherwise, all event activity will wait. You can use [threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) or [executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) (see also this: http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools/) to achieve that. This vastly depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Methods of Swing GUI classes should always be called on the [EDT thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) - see e.g. these for in-depth explanation if you are interested:

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kgh/archive/2004/10/multithreaded_t.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

One stylistic thing - you named your class `textareaStream`. It's a de facto standard that Java classes should begin with a capital letter.

Comment: Thank you! The executors and thread pools article is exactly what I was looking for. It works like a charm. I really appreciate the level of detail you put into the answer, even the style note.